# How do I know whether ARM Trustzone is in use or not?

Tags: arm, trustzone

I have a testboard, CPU is A72. I see that A72 supports Trustzone, but how do I know whether Trustzone is in use or not? Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide any information on the board and/or your software environment (bare-metal, RTOS, Linux,...)?

Comment: The chip is called RK3399, currently, I run Ubuntu 18.04 on it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the target is a RK3399 running Linux, this is likely that Arm Trusted Firmware, implementing TrustZone for Aarch64, is being used.

You can check by looking at the documentation, build procedure or source code of your Linux distribution. For example, Armbian is using ATF.

If you have a serial console connected to your system, you should see ATF log messages at boot time - You can find a USB-TTL adapter for $1.50 those days.

I suggested you provide more information on the distribution you are using, but Googling using your distribution name and 'ATF' or 'Arm Trusted Firmware' will likely answer your question if you choose not to.